# Why FLOAT type data comparison is not working even providing the exact data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, floating-point, precision

In real table with the same value

```
SELECT * FROM float_value WHERE val = 49640.2473896214 -- No data returns
```

If I round it upto the total precision then it works

```
SELECT * FROM float_value WHERE ROUND(val, 10) = ROUND(49640.2473896214, 10) --Returning Data
```

After that I have created temporaty table with the same value `49640.2473896214` and it works in the first query which is failed above

```
CREATE TABLE #testing(Vvalue FLOAT)
INSERT INTO #testing VALUES (49640.2473896214)

SELECT * FROM #testing WHERE Vvalue = 49640.2473896214 -- Simply returning row
```

Would you please help me to figure out this why `=` comparison is not working in the above ? If I should use `ROUND` always then it would be another problem to figure out the precision to be rounded and compare.

I want the result if we provide input what exactly visible in the field i.e. `= 49640.2473896214` should return value.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Every float value is an approximation, that's why equals does not work with that data type.

Comment: But same query is working when I checked it with temporary table.

Comment: it might, or might not work, perhaps you truncated the precision in the temp table? could be other reasons, but you will always have issues attempting equals with float data type

Comment: @Used_By_Already is right, but to try and understand why it didn't work and now seems to work... Did you use INSERT INTO float_values VALUES (49640.2473896214) or was the data already in there? Are the table schemas exactly the same?

Comment: Schemas exactly same and data was already in the table. Should I use `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` instead to get rid of this issue or any alternative please ?

Comment: If you insert 49640.2473896214 into the table and select from this table you see the value... the question is: what is the exact value in your val column in the first query?

Comment: The `exact value` in val column may be as similar as `actual_value` in my example. Thanks a lot your statement worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating point numbers cannot represent values exactly as you want, for example:

- 49640.2473896214321 gets stored as 49640.2473896214287378825247287750244140625
- 49640.2473896214521 gets stored as 49640.247389621450565755367279052734375
- 17.56 gets stored as... left as exercise

It is also worth noting that the *displayed* value of floats is usually an approximation. Some environments allow you to change the precision of the displayed value but I could not find any such setting in SQL server. Having said all that:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM float_value WHERE val = 49640.2473896214 -- No data returns
> ```

That is because `49640.2473896214` does not exist in the database. The value in database could be `...62139...` or `...62141...`, who knows.

> Would you please help me to figure out this why = comparision is not
>   working in the above?

It should work if you supply the exact value stored in database (used in previous INSERT or UPDATE operation). If you supply the value you *see* in the database then see notes above.

> If I should use ROUND always then it would be another problem to
>   figure out the precision to be rounded and compare.

ROUNDing returns FLOAT for FLOATs so you could end up with similar issues. The most cited solution for this problem is subtract the two numbers and check if the difference is *very* small:

```
select * from #testing WHERE ABS(vvalue - 49640.24738962     ) < 1e-11
-- id | vvalue           | actual_value
-- 1  | 49640.24738962   | 49640.24738962

select * from #testing WHERE ABS(vvalue - 49640.2473896214   ) < 1e-11
-- id | vvalue           | actual_value
-- 2  | 49640.2473896214 | 49640.2473896214

select * from #testing WHERE ABS(vvalue - 49640.2473896214321) < 1e-11
-- id | vvalue           | actual_value
-- 3  | 49640.2473896214 | 49640.2473896214321

select * from #testing WHERE ABS(vvalue - 49640.2473896214521) < 1e-11
-- id | vvalue           | actual_value
-- 4  | 49640.2473896215 | 49640.2473896214521
```

The `1e-11` is referred to as epsilon, the amount of tolerance you can accept. You can set it to something smaller but not smaller than `1e-16` as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

> Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly. 
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql

This can be very frustrating, but some float values will fail comparisons by the equal operator and it is necessary to fix the decimal precision to enable reliable use of equal.

Comment: Your text is quite enough to know the reason of that issue. Thank you. Can you please suggest me the alternative of that ?

Comment: "it depends" & I know nothing about your requirements, you "probably" want a decimal (*numeric* is just a synonym) see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql

Comment: @Susang If you want fixed precision, use DECIMAL or NUMERIC data types instead. FLOAT and REAL should be rare, unless you're not worried about storing numbers precisely (e.g. statistics).

Comment: In spite of the Microsoft documentation, floating-point types do not approximate numbers. IEEE 754 is a more authoritative document. In floating-point arithmetic, the numbers exactly represent some set of real numbers. The operations return values rounded to representable results. So it is the operations that are approximate, not the numbers. This distinction is critical to understanding how to work with floating-point arithmetic properly.

Answer (score 1):

Now, I understand the scenario of `FLOAT` field values as its storing upto 10 precision by rounding the given values

For Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #testing(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Vvalue FLOAT, actual_value VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #testing VALUES 
(49640.24738962, '49640.24738962'),
(49640.2473896214, '49640.2473896214'),
(49640.2473896214321, '49640.2473896214321'),
(49640.2473896214521, '49640.2473896214521')
```

value saved as:

```
id  Vvalue              actual_value
1   49640.24738962      49640.24738962      --Saved same as input
2   49640.2473896214    49640.2473896214    --Saved same as input
3   49640.2473896214    49640.2473896214321 --Saved upto 10 precision only by rounding leaving trailing zeros
4   49640.2473896215    49640.2473896214521 --Saved upto 10 precision only by rounding leaving trailing zeros
```

Now, Apparently following query should return two rows 2,3 but row 3 value is not exactly as out input

```
SELECT * FROM #testing WHERE Vvalue = 49640.2473896214 

id  Vvalue              actual_value
2   49640.2473896214    49640.2473896214
```

In my case, it should return both rows 2,3 so, if I round comparison column value by 10 then it will give what I want and it doesn't matter for me now, what unseen value it's holding ? I just simply want to receive what's present there in the table

```
SELECT * FROM #testing WHERE ROUND(Vvalue, 10) = 49640.2473896214

id  Vvalue              actual_value
2   49640.2473896214    49640.2473896214
3   49640.2473896214    49640.2473896214321
```

Thank you everyone for sharing your ideas and boost up my mind :)